# Filter result from inner Step Function

Tags: aws-step-functions

I have a Step Function that starts another Step Function.

The output from the inner step function is ok, it is exactly what I want.

Here is the code that triggers the outer step function:

```
{
  "StartAt": "MySF",
  "States": {
    "Textract": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "OutputPath": "$",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync:2",
      "Parameters": {
        "Input": {
          "input.$": "$$.Execution.Input"
        },
        "StateMachineArn": "inner_step_function_arn"
      },
      "End": true
    }
  },
  "TimeoutSeconds": 3600
}
```

If I look on the outer step function, the result of the inner step function has much more stuff than I need, and it is basically metadata of that execution, like below:

```
{
  "ExecutionArn": "inner_step_function_arn"
  "Input": {
    "input": {
        the output that I need
    }
  },
  "InputDetails": {
    "Included": true
  },
  "Name": "xxx",
  "Output": {
    the output that I need
  },
  "OutputDetails": {
    "Included": true
  },
  "StartDate": 1637923353831,
  "StateMachineArn": "inner_step_function_arn,
  "Status": "SUCCEEDED",
  "StopDate": 1637923386955
}
```

So my question is how to have as a result only what is inside `"input"` node.
Is there a way to filter only the Input ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out the required result only from the outer step function with [ResultSelector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html). It allows selecting fields that you need.
Your SF definition should look like this:

```
{
  "StartAt": "MySF",
  "States": {
    "Textract": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "OutputPath": "$",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync:2",
      "Parameters": {
        "Input": {
          "input.$": "$$.Execution.Input"
        },
        "StateMachineArn": "inner_step_function_arn"
      },
      "ResultSelector": {
        "Output.$": "$.Output"
      },
      "End": true
    }
  },
  "TimeoutSeconds": 3600
}
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks. It seems to work. But I still have the "Output" node as output. Is it possible to have only what is inside "Ouput" without the "Output" node ?